# EaselJs: How to restrict image movement inside canvas (after scaling or rotation)?

Tags: css, canvas, html5-canvas, createjs, easeljs

I'm creating a simple image cropping tool using EaselJs (similar to [this](http://bcabanes.github.io/angular-image-cropper/)). So far I have written most of the code except one small issue. I want the image to remain inside the container when I drag it. In other words, I don't want the background to show under the image.

Please see my code:

```js
var img = new Image();
var canvas, stage, bmp;

img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/wMW4nDL.jpg?timestamp=' + Math.random();
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

img.onload = function() {  
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
  bmp = new createjs.Bitmap(img).set();

  bmp.on("pressmove", function(evt) {
    var ct = evt.currentTarget;

    ct.x = evt.stageX;
    ct.y = evt.stageY;

    stage.update();
  });

  bmp.on('mousedown', function(evt) {
    var ct = evt.currentTarget,
      local = ct.globalToLocal(evt.stageX, evt.stageY),
      nx = ct.regX - local.x,
      ny = ct.regY - local.y;
    //set the new regX/Y
    ct.regX = local.x;
    ct.regY = local.y;
    //adjust the real-position, otherwise the new regX/Y would cause a jump
    ct.x -= nx;
    ct.y -= ny;
  });
  
  bmp.regX = img.width / 2;
  bmp.regY = img.height / 2;
  bmp.x = bmp.y = 300;
  bmp.scaleX = bmp.scaleY = 0.5;
  
  bmp.rotation = 90;
  stage.addChild(bmp);  
  stage.update();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="200" style="cursor:move;border:2px solid red">Canvas is not supported</canvas>
```

Run the code and keep dragging the image down. Soon the image will go outside the canvas and you will start seeing the white canvas under it. I want the image to stop dragging if the image's top-corner is greater than (0, 0) relative to canvas. Same for bottom, I want it to stop dragging if the bottom of image is being dragged even after hitting the canvas bottom.

**How can I update my code so that the image stops dragging when it goes outside the canvas?** (from both top-left, bottom-left, top-right or bottom-right)

Answer (score 2):

I recently did something similar with createJS. Basically what you want to do is to restrict the movement of the image in the `pressmove` listener, like this:

```
if (ct.x > 0){
    ct.x = 0;
}
```

and of course applied for all the possible movement scenarios.

Below is part of my own code that I used to enforce these exact bounds. What is different however in my own code is that I also had to enforce the bounds for the zoomed-in image. Maybe it will be of some use to you.

```
    function handleMouse(me)
    {

        switch (me.type){
            case "mousedown":
                _initialX = _stage.mouseX;
                _initialY = _stage.mouseY;
                break;
            case "pressmove":
                if (_imageOrientation == "portrait"){
                    handlePortraitMovement();
                } else if (_imageOrientation == "landscape"){
                    handleLandscapeMovement();
                }

                _overlayerImageCopy.x = _imagesContainer.x;
                _overlayerImageCopy.y = _imagesContainer.y;

                _initialX = _stage.mouseX;
                _initialY = _stage.mouseY;
                _stage.update();
                break;
        }

    }

    function handlePortraitMovement()
    {
        var alphaOfMovement;
        if (_stage.mouseX - _initialX > 0){
            //up movement
            alphaOfMovement = -1;
        } else {
            //down movement
            alphaOfMovement = 1;
        }
        _imagesContainer.y += _stage.mouseY - _initialY;
        if (_imagesContainer.y >= _maxMovementPosition){
            _imagesContainer.y = _maxMovementPosition;
        }
        if (_imagesContainer.y < -_maxMovementPosition + _canvas.height * (1 - _imagesContainer.scaleY)){
            _imagesContainer.y = -_maxMovementPosition + _canvas.height * (1 - _imagesContainer.scaleY);
        }
        if ((alphaOfMovement == 1) && (-_imagesContainer.x + SQUARE_SIZE < SQUARE_SIZE * _imagesContainer.scaleX)){
            _imagesContainer.x += _stage.mouseX - _initialX;
            if (-_imagesContainer.x + SQUARE_SIZE > SQUARE_SIZE * _imagesContainer.scaleX) {
                _imagesContainer.x = SQUARE_SIZE - SQUARE_SIZE * _imagesContainer.scaleX;
            }
        }
        if (alphaOfMovement == 1 && _imagesContainer.x > 0){
            _imagesContainer.x = 0;
        }
        if (alphaOfMovement == -1 && _imagesContainer.x < 0){
            _imagesContainer.x += _stage.mouseX - _initialX;
        }
    }

    function handleLandscapeMovement()
    {
        var alphaOfMovement;
        if (_stage.mouseY - _initialY > 0){
            //left movement
            alphaOfMovement = -1;
        } else {
            //right movement
            alphaOfMovement = 1;
        }
        _imagesContainer.x += _stage.mouseX - _initialX;
        if (_imagesContainer.x >= _maxMovementPosition){
            _imagesContainer.x = _maxMovementPosition;
        }
        if (_imagesContainer.x < -_maxMovementPosition + _canvas.width * (1 - _imagesContainer.scaleX)){
            _imagesContainer.x = -_maxMovementPosition + _canvas.width * (1 - _imagesContainer.scaleX);
        }
        if ((alphaOfMovement == 1) && (-_imagesContainer.y + SQUARE_SIZE < SQUARE_SIZE * _imagesContainer.scaleY)){
            _imagesContainer.y += _stage.mouseY - _initialY;
            if (-_imagesContainer.y + SQUARE_SIZE > SQUARE_SIZE * _imagesContainer.scaleY) {
                _imagesContainer.y = SQUARE_SIZE - SQUARE_SIZE * _imagesContainer.scaleY;
            }
        }
        if (alphaOfMovement == 1 && _imagesContainer.y > 0){
            _imagesContainer.y = 0;
        }
        if (alphaOfMovement == -1 && _imagesContainer.y < 0){
            _imagesContainer.y += _stage.mouseY - _initialY;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, this looks very useful. I'm going it over line by line to understand it.  I think the hardest part of containing it is when the image is rotated, because then the X & Y values get really confusing..

Comment: Yeah, it was a pain to design from scratch. The best you can hope for is to define rules of movement in all 4 directions, like I did using `alphaOfMovement`.